# What is the meaning of the phrasal verb "to give something up to someone?"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

I heard it in a movie. Some boys were showing their skills with a ball. After watching all the boys' tries, the coach said, "give it up to Jordan." Then, all the boys cheered Jordan.

Comment: Did you check any dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

The expression "Give it up for Jordaan" is an idiom meaning "applaud Jordan". It is often heard in entertainment venues (at least in the US) when an MC or presenter is introducing a performer, and sometimes at the conclusion of a performance or section of a performance.  One might hear something like:

> Here all the way from Neverland, let's give it up for Jane Wonderful!

It is essentially the equivalent of the older "Let's have a big hand for ..."

In the context provided "give it up to " seems to be a variant with the same meaning

In other contexts "give it up to X" could mean "give it to X" with the implication that the gift  is something of a sacrifice.

> I know you've liked having your own room, but I want you to give it up to John.

Answer (score 0):

"Give it up" to, or for, someone can mean "give applause to that person"

> give it up for someone
>
> PHRASE
>
> ​SPOKEN used to ask people to applaud someone Please give it up for
> Lin-Manuel Miranda and the entire cast!

[Give it up for someone (Macmillan Dictionary)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/give-it-up-for-someone)